# Modify pandas series inplace, update reference to modified entries automatically

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas series, such as `my_series` below. I would like to create a reference to some of the values so that the reference is updated whenever the original series is updated.

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> my_series = pd.Series(dict(x=0, y=1, z=2))
>>> my_series
x    0
y    1
z    2
dtype: int64

>>> reference = my_series[['x', 'y']] # This doesn't work
>>> my_series.x = 10
>>> reference
x    0
y    1
dtype: int64
```

My desired output would be

```py
>>> reference
x    10
y    1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use loc

```
>>> my_series = pd.Series(dict(x=0, y=1, z=2))
>>> reference = my_series.loc['x':'y']
>>> my_series.x = 10
>>> reference
x    10
y     1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Modifying `reference` in this way does not change the corresponding entry of `my_series`