# Pandas Series .loc[[0,1]] versus .loc[0:1]

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, slice

*tl;dr: Why does `.loc[[0,1]]` seem to create a copy while `.loc[0:1]` seems to create a reference?*

---

While searching for an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57419173/9235855), I found out that `.loc[[0,1]]` behaves differently from `.loc[0:1]`. For example, if I have a pandas Series such as:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> my_series = pd.Series(dict(x=0, y=1, z=2))
>>> my_series
x    0
y    1
z    2
dtype: int64
```

and I index into it using `.loc[['x','y']]`, this seems to create a copy

```py
>>> my_series = pd.Series(dict(x=0, y=1, z=2))
>>> reference = my_series.loc[['x', 'y']]
>>> my_series.x = 10
>>> reference
x    0
y    1
dtype: int64
```

whereas when I index into it using `.loc['x':'y']`, this seems to create a reference

```py
>>> my_series = pd.Series(dict(x=0, y=1, z=2))
>>> reference = my_series.loc['x':'y']
>>> my_series.x = 10
>>> reference
x    10
y    1
dtype: int64
```

*What is going on here?*

---

The same behavior persists omitting `.loc` as in

```py
>>> reference = my_series[['x', 'y']]
```

and

```py
>>> reference = my_series['x':'y']
```

---

I have seen this page in the docs [Returning a view versus a copy](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy), but it does not explain the observed difference in behavior.

Comment: Make sure you reset `my_series.x` back to `0` before you create the second reference, otherwise even if it *did* return a copy `x` would be `10`

Comment: @user3483203 Thanks for pointing that out, I've updated the example code in the question.

Comment: From [docs](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/user_guide/indexing.html#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing) "Outside of simple cases, it’s very hard to predict whether it will return a view or a copy (it depends on the memory layout of the array, about which pandas makes no guarantees)..."

Comment: @ScottBoston The section of the docs you linked to is about chained indexing. Have I used chained indexing somewhere and not noticed? Or does the comment made in that section of the docs apply more broadly?

Comment: I think in general, but I can't find documentation of exact when a view is returned vs a copy.

Comment: Since `pandas` uses `numpy` underneath, I think this behavior is consistent with Numpy arrays' handling of fancy indexing (i.e. accessing elements using an indexing array). You may find some documentation here: https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/ViewsVsCopies.html

Comment: Surely the issue is that a slice has a known (contiguous) structure but indexing with a list cannot be expressed so efficiently?